# Rename a database on Azure SQL Managed Instance that is part of geo-replication

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance, geo-replication

I have an Azure SQL Managed Instance that is set up with geo-replication.  I have a database on this MI that I want to swap out with another database by renaming them:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb MODIFY NAME = mydb_old; 
ALTER DATABASE mydb_new MODIFY NAME = mydb;
```

When I run this, I get an error error:

> The operation cannot be performed since the database 'mydb' is in a replication relationship.

What do I need to do to allow me to rename the databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, database rename does not work if Geo-replication is enabled. The same behavior is in Azure SQL Database - Singleton, so generally RENAME and Geo-replication don't work together in Azure SQL.

Could you file this in SQL DB feedback forum highlighting that rename should be supported if Geo-replication is setup on database/instance so people could vote for this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database

Comment: Posted [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/41115205-rename-a-database-on-azure-sql-managed-instance-th).  What is the proper workaround?

Comment: I got this same error and see my answer as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem today and as mentioned in the approved answer, you can't rename an Azure database if the Geo-replication is enabled.

In order to rename my database, I ended up deleting my failover group and then stopped my replication. Further details are below.

PS: I have got a script to regenerate the replications again, so deletion is not a problem for my case.

[image]

[image]

[image]